# .NET CORE Worker Service won't read controllers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to create an API Host inside a worker Service, therefore in the CreateDefaultBuilder I tried adding a WebBuilder like the following code

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                IConfiguration config = hostContext.Configuration;
                
                Configuration Configurations = config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Get<Configuration>();
                
                
                services.AddSingleton(Configurations);
                services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, DataAccess>();
                
                services.AddHostedService<ATMListener>();
                services.AddHostedService<DBListener>();
                services.AddControllers();
            })
         .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
         {
             webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseUrls("https://*:44378");
             
         })
        .ConfigureWebHost(config => 
        {
            config.UseUrls("https://*:8080");
            
        });
```

and in startup class I use the following code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();
      
        app.UseAuthorization();

        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            //endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                 name: "Home",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
                ) ;
            Log.Warning("Created Controller");
        });
    }
```

The endpoint is working fine and I tested it using enpoint.MapGet("/"... ) and it worked and returned the values...
However I Created a controller called HomeController : ControllerBase

```
 //[Route("[controller]")]
//[ApiController]
[Controller]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
  

    //[HttpGet]
    //[Route("Test")]
    public string Index()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

}
```

The Startup doesn't read the Controller, so when I type  https://localhost:8080/controller/function it doesn't return anything at all .. so How do I make it work?

Please note that I tried to add Owin and SelfHost dependencies but it seems not compatible with .NETCore and the dependency keeps on rolling back.

Comment: "I tried a lot to make the endpoint reach the controller but it won't" is not a problem statement we can assist with. Edit your question with **specific details** of what you tried and didn't work.

Comment: @IanKemp I edited the statement maybe you can understand the issue now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question title is very strange?
Use endpoints without path maps etc:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

add route attribute to controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
  

    
    public string Index()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

}
```

Comment: I discovered that the Controller class was not public so the MapController was not reading it